# Rails form submit handler not being executed

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, balanced-payments

I'm trying to integrate Balanced Payments to allow users to save their credit card information for use at a later time. The relevant view code and javascript files are as follows, but I'm having trouble with the submit handler defined in the javascript file.

**balanced_card.js**

```
var marketplaceUri = '{MY MARKETPLACE URI}';
var requestBinUrl = '{FORM SUBMISSION PATH}'

var debug = function(tag, content) {
    $('<' + tag + '>' + content + '</' + tag + '>').appendTo('#result');
};

try {
    balanced.init(marketplaceUri);
} catch (e) {
    debug('code', 'balanced.init error!');
}

function balancedCallback(response) {
    var tag = (response.status < 300) ? 'pre' : 'code';
    debug(tag, JSON.stringify(response));
    switch(response.status) {
        case 201:
            console.log(response.data);
            var $form = $("#credit-card-form");
            var card_token_uri = response.data['uri'];
            $('<input>').attr({
                type: 'hidden',
                value: card_token_uri,
                name: 'balancedCreditCardURI'
            }).appendTo($form);
            $form.attr({action: requestBinUrl});
            $form.get(0).submit();
        case 400:
            console.log(response.error);
        case 404:
            console.log(response.error);
            break;
    }
}

var tokenizeCreditCard = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $form = $('#credit-card-form');
    var creditCardData = {
        card_number: $form.find('.cc-number').val(),
        expiration_month: $form.find('.cc-em').val(),
        expiration_year: $form.find('.cc-ey').val(),
        security_code: $form.find('.cc-csc').val()
    }

    balanced.card.create(creditCardData, balancedCallback);
};

$('#credit-card-form').submit(tokenizeCreditCard);
```

**credit_card.html.haml**

```
= javascript_include_tag 'https://js.balancedpayments.com/v1/balanced.js'

= javascript_include_tag 'balanced_card'

= render :partial => 'crdtcard'
```

**_crdtcard.html.haml**

```
%h3 Credit Card
= form_tag '#', :method => :post, :id => "credit-card-form" do
  = label_tag "Card Number"
  = text_field_tag "cc-number", nil, :placeholder => "Enter Credit Card Number", :class => "cc-number", :autocomplete => "off"
  = label_tag "Expiration"
  = text_field_tag "cc-em", nil, :placeholder => "Expiration Month", :class => "cc-em", :autocomplete => "off"
  = text_field_tag "cc-em", nil, :placeholder => "Expiration Year", :class => "cc-ey", :autocomplete => "off"
  = label_tag "Security Code"
  = text_field_tag "cc-csc", nil, :placeholder => "Security Code", :class => "cc-csc", :autocomplete => "off"
  = submit_tag "Submit", :name => "submit"
```

tokenizeCreditCard never seems to get called when I debug with Firebug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed wrapping your bind inside a `onDomready` event:

```
$(function(){
  $('#credit-card-form').submit(tokenizeCreditCard);
})
```