# Balanced Payments - Routing Error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, balanced-payments

For my application, I have Users. I am trying to utilize Balanced Payments to allow users to save their credit card information for use at a later time. I have followed the two links below as guide and currently have the following error:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/store_credit_card"
```

I followed this [GIST](https://gist.github.com/sicophrenic/5312831) and [Rails form submit handler not being executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422618/rails-form-submit-handler-not-being-executed).

- `balanced_controller.rb` - created
- `_credit_card_form.html.haml` - created and put under `app>view>balanced`
- `credit_card_submission.js` - created and put under `app>assets>javascript`
- Added a field `:balanced_account_uri string` in my user model
- Replaced the placeholder text in the .js files for the Balanced marketplace uri
- Updated routes.rb for the methods in balanced_controller.rb

Does somebody know why it is not working?

**routes.rb**

```
resources :users do
    resources :balanced do
      member do
        post :store_credit_card, :create_balanced_account
      end
    end
end
```

**view/users/edit.html.erb**

```
<div class = "container">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.balancedpayments.com/v1/balanced.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    balanced.init('YOUR MARKETPLACE URI HERE');
</script>

<%= render 'balanced/credit_card_form' %>

</div>
```

**view/balanced/_credit_card_form.html.haml**

```
= form_tag "/store_credit_card", :method => :post, :id => "credit-card-form", :class => "form-horizontal" do
  .control-group
    = label_tag "cc-number", "Card Number", :class => "control-label"
    .controls
      = text_field_tag "cc-number", nil, :placeholder => "Enter Credit Card Number", :class => "cc-number", :autocomplete => "off"
  .control-group
    = label_tag "cc-em", "Expiration", :class => "control-label"
    .controls
      = text_field_tag "cc-em", nil, :placeholder => "Expiration Month", :class => "cc-em", :autocomplete => "off"
      = text_field_tag "cc-em", nil, :placeholder => "Expiration Year", :class => "cc-ey", :autocomplete => "off"
  .control-group
    = label_tag "cc-csc", "Security Code", :class => "control-label"
    .controls
      = text_field_tag "cc-csc", nil, :placeholder => "Security Code", :class => "cc-csc", :autocomplete => "off"
  .control-group
    .controls
      = submit_tag "Submit", :class => "btn btn-primary btn-large"
```

**assets/javascript/credit_card_submissions.js**

```
var marketplaceUri = 'YOUR MARKETPLACE URI HERE';
var requestBinUrl = '/store_credit_card'


var debug = function(tag, content) {
  $('<' + tag + '>' + content + '</' + tag + '>').appendTo('#result');
};

try {
balanced.init(marketplaceUri);
} catch (e) {
debug('code', 'balanced.init error!');
}

function balancedCallback(response) {
var tag = (response.status < 300) ? 'pre' : 'code';
debug(tag, JSON.stringify(response));
switch(response.status) {
    case 201:
        console.log(response.data);
        var $form = $("#credit-card-form");
        var card_token_uri = response.data['uri'];
        $('<input>').attr({
            type: 'hidden',
            value: card_token_uri,
            name: 'balancedCreditCardURI'
        }).appendTo($form);
        $form.attr({action: requestBinUrl});
        $form.get(0).submit();
        break;
    case 400:
        console.log(response.error);
        break;
    case 404:
        console.log(response.error);
        break;
}
}

var tokenizeCreditCard = function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var $form = $('#credit-card-form');
var creditCardData = {
    card_number: $form.find('.cc-number').val(),
    expiration_month: $form.find('.cc-em').val(),
    expiration_year: $form.find('.cc-ey').val(),
    security_code: $form.find('.cc-csc').val()
};

balanced.card.create(creditCardData, balancedCallback);
};

$(function(){
$('#credit-card-form').submit(tokenizeCreditCard);
});
```

**balanced_controller.rb**

```
class BalancedController < ApplicationController
  def create_balanced_account
    current_user.balanced_account_uri = Balanced::Marketplace.my_marketplace.create_account(:email => current_user.email, :type => 'person').uri
    current_user.save
    # add a redirect to the desired path
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def store_credit_card
    balanced_account = Balanced::Account.find(current_user.balanced_account_uri)
    balanced_account.add_card(params[:balancedCreditCardURI])
    # add a redirect to the desired path
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def store_bank_account
    balanced_account = Balanced::Account.find(current_user.balanced_account_uri)
    balanced_account.add_card(params[:balancedBankAccountURI])
    # add a redirect to the desired path
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def process_payment
    balanced_account = Balanced::Account.find(current_user.balanced_account_uri)
    account.debit(
      :amount => 1000, # or params[:amount]
      :description => "Balanced Payments transaction",
      :appears_on_statement_as => "Balanced Payments")
    # add a redirect to the desired path
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not a ruby person but have you registered your route with the routing engine?

Answer (score 0):

According to your routes your post path would not be `"/store_credit_card"` but something like `"users/:user_id/balanced/:balanced_id/store_credit_card"`

So you'll need to change `form_tag "/store_credit_card"` to match that.

Run `rake routes` to see your routes as they are currently defined.

Also, you can use the url helper generated by your routes instead of a string in `form_tag`:

```
form_tag users_balanced_store_credit_card_path(@user, @balanced)
```

The above may be wrong, `rake routes` will tell you the exact path and helper name.