# jQuery submit handler with Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying out jQuery with Rails and I faced this problem. I want to have a jQuery [submit handler](http://api.jquery.com/submit/#submit-handler) for a [button_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) tag like this

```
<%= button_to "+", action: "execute", operation: "add", operand: "1" %>
```

which is actually converted to a form in the DOM like so

```
<form class="button_to" method="post" action="/execute?operand=1&amp;operation=add">
<input type="submit" value="+">
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="mre8xqU4RBk2u+vCLrMQHYUHTNWtk0Ebn45OnvlXxUZcofqxArt9ZXJN63QlNq8Kei08FFo6Y4+OQgwH+vsVNw==">
</form>
```

I added a submit handler for this form which looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  ("form").submit(function(){
      alert("here");
    });
});
```

The alert doesn't get displayed when I submit the form. I also tried the solution of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422618/rails-form-submit-handler-not-being-executed) but it didn't help.

My aim is to set the value of the value of the `operand` attribute in the `button_to` tag to `$(".operand").text()` inside the submit handler. Operand is another text field in which the user has entered a numeric value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a '$'

```
  ("form").submit(function(){
      alert("here");
   });
```

Should be

```
  $("form").submit(function(){
      alert("here");
  });
```